# Error with phpize in SLES

Tags: php

I'm trying to run the `phpize` command, but i keep getting this error message:

```
Cannot find config.m4
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize in top level source directory of the module
```

I have already installed `php5-dev`.

Comment: Try to use `/usr/bin/phpize` istead of `phpize`. Also execute `which phpize` and  `whereis phpize`.

Comment: it didn't help help, but I solve it my problem now is when I'm runing
    phpize
    ./configure
    make
    make install 
I got this error message 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [saprfc.la] Error 1